# Anybody knows why is this compiling successfully?

Tags: c

Anybody knows why is [this](http://ideone.com/8wOORD) compiling successfully in C?

```
int main(){
     display();
   return 0;
 } 

 void display(){
     printf("Why am I compiling successfully?");
 }
```

I thought when declaration is not provided C assume `extern int Function_name(arg1,arg2,...){}.` Thus this should give an error but however it's working! I know that Ideone is supressing the warnings but my question is why is it just not giving a straight error? (however in C++ it's straight error)

Comment: for what matters to this question, I always find useful to enable extra warnings like with `gcc -Wall -Wextra` so you can be more pedantic about what your compiler is doing.

Comment: [check the warnings](http://rextester.com/LHF3823)

Answer (score 8):

**Turn up the warning level in your compiler** and you should get 2 warnings,

`display` not declared, `int` assumed

and

`display` redeclared

**Edit:**

Older versions of C (pre C99) aren't really that bothered about return types or argument types. You could say it's part of the K&R legacy. For instance, if you don't explicitly specify the argument types, the compiler won't check them at all.

C++ is stricter, which IMO is a good thing. I always provide declarations and always specify the argument lists when I code in C.

Comment: Yes I know it's giving an warning but shouldn't it give a straight error?

Comment: ... and it complains about `printf`, too.

Comment: @vlad : Interesting, so now declaration is made optional (implementation defined)?

Comment: @Quixotic: I suspect this behaviour to be legacy (but not sure).

Comment: You are using a buil-in `printf`. Never forget to include `stdio.h`.

Comment: C isn't really that bothered about return types or argument types. You could say it's part of the K&R legacy. If you don't explicitly specify the argument types, the compiler won't check them at all. C++ is stricter, which IMO is a good thing. I always provide declarations and always specify the argument lists when I code in C.

Comment: @Quixotic No, declaration is mandatory in C (since C99). What is not mandatory, however, is that a compiler refuses to compile an ill-formed programme. It must give a diagnostic, but then it can choose to continue compilation to produce an executable or not. If it produces an executable from an ill-formed programme, the language standard doesn't say anything about its behaviour, of course. If you compile with gcc, the language you compile by default is gnu89 (C89+GNU-extensions), which allows implicit declarations (C89). The conflicting types are still forbidden by the standard, though.

Answer (score 5):

It's compiling because C uses a lot of defaults to be backwards compatible. In K&R C, you couldn't specify function prototypes, so the compiler would just assume that you know what you're doing when you call a function.

Later (at least ANSI C, but maybe even in C99), C didn't really have a way to distinguish

```
void display(void);
void display();
```

so the empty declaration must be accepted as well.

That's why you can call `display()` without defining it first.

`printf()` is similar. You will get a linker error if you forget `-lc` but from the compiler's point of view, the code is "good enough".

That will change as soon as you enable all warnings that your compiler has to offer and it will fail with an error when you disable K&C compatibility or enable strict ANSI checks.

Which is why "C" is often listed as "you shoot yourself into the foot" in "[How to Shoot Yourself In the Foot Using Any Programming Language](http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Humor/Docs/ShootYourselfInTheFoot.html)" kind of lists.

Comment: In C99, the declarations `void display(void);` and `void display();` mean different things. The latter doesn't specify the number or types of arguments, the former specifies it takes no arguments. And in C99, a function must be declared before it is used. But a compiler is not obliged to reject ill-formed programmes, only a diagnostic is required.

Answer (score 3):

it depends of your Cx (C89, C90, C99,...)

for function return values, prior to C99 it was explicitly speciﬁed that if no function declaration was visible the translator provided one. These implicit declarations defaulted to a return type of int

Justification from [C Standard](http://www.coding-guidelines.com/cbook/cbook1_0b.pdf) (6.2.5 page 506)

> Prior to C90 there were no function prototypes. Developers expected to
>   be able to interchange argu-ments that had signed and unsigned
>   versions of the same integer type. Having to cast an argument, if the
>   parameter type in the function deﬁnition had a different signedness,
>   was seen as counter to C’s easy-going type-checking system and a
>   little intrusive. The introduction of prototypes did not completely do
>   away with the issue of interchangeability of arguments. The ellipsis
>   notation speciﬁes that nothing is known about the 1590 ellipsis
>   supplies no information expected type of arguments. Similarly, for
>   function return values, prior to C99 it was explicitly speciﬁed that
>   if no function declaration was visible the translator provided one.
>   These implicit declarations defaulted to a return type of int . If the
>   actual function happened to return the type unsigned int , such a
>   default declaration might have returned an unexpected result. A lot of
>   developers had a casual attitude toward function declarations. The
>   rest of us have to live with the consequences of the Committee not
>   wanting to break all the source code they wrote. The
>   interchangeability of function return values is now a moot point,
>   because C99 requires that a function declaration be visible at the
>   point of call (a default declaration is no longer provided)

Answer (score 1):

It probably does (assume such declaration as you wrote), but as you are not passing parameters, it just works fine. It's the same like if you declare `int main()` where it should actually be `int  main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

So probably if you tried to pass some parameters (different from default ones) from `main` then use them in `display` it would fail.

BTW, for me it compiles, but generates warning:

```
$ gcc z.c
z.c:8:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘display’ [enabled by default]
z.c:4:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘display’ was here
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why it accepts `printf()` - he doesn't include `stdio.h`.

Comment: OK, I thought it's just a mistake - but after removing `#include <stdio.h>` it still compiles and works fine. So I guess, it's similar mechanism. It assumes printf(int, int, ...) - and when calling, it convert `char*` to the int and put it to the stack. It so happens, that `sizeof(char*)==sizeof(int)`, so when actual `printf` tries to get `char*` from the stack - it converts it back from int and it get proper pointer to the string. HTH.

Comment: Some compilers will automatically include common libraries such as stdio.h if you forget to tell them to.  Dev C++ is one such compiler that's more popular than it should be.  Personally, I consider this to be a very bad feature, as it means people using other compilers won't be able to compile your code.  It's one of the main reasons I stopped using Dev C++.

Answer (score 0):

When I compile with gcc, I get warnings about redeclaration of `display`, as you would expect.

Did you get warnings?

It might "run" because C doesn't mangle function names (like C++). So the linker looks for a symbol 'display' and finds one. The linker uses this address to run `display`. I would expect results to not be what you expect all the time.